# My New ViewController is giving SIGABRT error?

Tags: ios, swift3, sigabrt

I have many different buttons like UIStepper and DatePicker and a MapView. Can anyone help me get my whole view controller and the button working. I have been getting an error about SIGABRT. It say's "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Field_Service_Report.AddController hoursStepper:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb5d7c8d010'"

This is my View Controller code :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class AddController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var hoursStepperResult: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var hoursStepper: UIStepper!

@IBOutlet weak var minutesStepperResult: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var minutesStepper: UIStepper!

@IBOutlet weak var currentLocationLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var dateOfReport: UIDatePicker!

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Start Map Contents
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    // End Map Contents

}

// Start Stepper Contents

@IBAction func hoursStepperAction(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    hoursStepperResult.text = String(Int(sender.value))
}

@IBAction func minutesStepperAction(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    minutesStepperResult.text = String(Int(sender.value))
}


// End Stepper Contents

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
// Here is the new code its giving me 3 erroe because im trying to get the text and numbers from another ViewController to print out in this VC.

@IBAction func doneACButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let newVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultController") as! ResultController
    newVC.intPassed = hoursIntProvided
    newVC.intPassed = minutesIntProvided
    newVC.stringPassed = resultedHours.text!

}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
}



// MARK: - Navigation


}
```

Comment: From where do you instantiate this view controller? Please show that code

Comment: I've been getting many errors on the things in the method. I added the code to the bottom of the existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the colon right here in the method signature:

```
-[Field_Service_Report.AddController hoursStepper:]
                                                 ^
```

This is the signature of a method that takes a parameter, not the signature of an accessor.  Are you sure you didn't misspell a selector name somewhere or leave something accidentally connected in IB that should have been removed?  (Perhaps if you renamed a method and forgot to redo the action connection?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've tried everything and I still couldn't figure it out now I'm just getting an error saying setValue: I have only 2 warnings from my app icon and when I play the app and click the button to go to the next VC it crashes and gives me that error.(SIGABRT)